# Compilation of two files from different compiler one is using other

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, runtime, clang++

If I  will compile something (x.cpp) with clang++ and generate dynamic link library, let's say x.so files and I will use that .so files in other source (y.cpp) which I am compiling using g++, so do I get any run time error.

Comment: Try it and tell us.

Comment: Might search for 'ABI'

Comment: In calling a DLL made with a different compiler, you are bravely entering a world where many different things can happen. See [Using C++ DLLs with different compiler versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/331045/10871073) for some possibly helpful tips.

Comment: This is known to break with different versions of the same compiler, let alone different compilers.

Comment: Mixing different compilers in the same project is very dangerous. Why do you have this requirement? Is it an option to compile everything with clang++ instead?

Comment: no like my  whole code is under g++ but now i am adding one cpp files which is using some "armnn" DLL which are build in clang++. so i need to run that cpp with clang++ otherwise i am getting runtime crash. and i can not complie whole armnn library in g++

Comment: So why not compile everything with clang++?

Comment: mostly works if and only if it's same version C++ and -pedantic and other generalizing arch./machine options