# WINAPI identifiers in function declaration C++ in DLL entrypoint function

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll, calling-convention

I'm just learning how to create a *dll* with C++.

There appears this :

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
```

And I can not understand what is `"WINAPI"` in `DllMain()`?

I know that a function is :

```
typeReturn functionName (params) { function body }
```

`typeReturn` : is the value that function returns,
`functionName` : is the name of the function,
`params` : are the parameters for the function,
{function body} : is the code inside in the function.
...

Then, following the explanation, what does `WINAPI` mean in C++ that or `__stdcall`?

I'm not asking what means `WINAPI` itself.

************ UPDATE **************

C++ has (calling conventions) that is used to put in memory each parameter given in a special way.
please read correctly the question and avoid mark it as duplicate, because people learning c/c++ needs learn without fall into confusions

Comment: For me, searching "WINAPI" in Google gives the answer in the first link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/what-does-winapi-in-main-function-mean

Comment: yes, but what does IN C++ mean?
can i write functions with extra identifier that crowns functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WINAPI` is defined as `__stdcall`.

Actually `__stdcall` is a *calling convention* And different calling conventions push parameters in different ways, Bellow are some of `c/c++` ***Calling Conventions :***

***In x86 :***

- ***`C` calling convention (`__cdecl`)***. The main characteristics of `__cdecl` calling convention are :

  1. Arguments are passed from right to left, and placed on the stack.
  2. Stack cleanup is performed by the caller.
  3. Function name is decorated by prefixing it with an underscore character '_' .
- ***Standard calling convention (`__stdcall`)***. The main characteristics of `__stdcall` calling convention are :

  1. Arguments are passed from right to left, and placed on the stack.
  2. Stack cleanup is performed by the called function.
  3. Function name is decorated by prepending an underscore character and appending a '@' character and the number of bytes of stack space required.
- ***Fast calling convention (`__fastcall`)***. he main characteristics of `__fastcall` calling convention are :

  1. The first two function arguments that require 32 bits or less are placed into registers **ECX** and **EDX**. The rest of them are pushed on the stack from right to left.
  2. Arguments are popped from the stack by the called function.
  3. Function name is decorated by by prepending a `'@'` character and appending a `'@'` and the number of bytes (decimal) of space required by the arguments.

[Consider to Read This Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1388/Calling-Conventions-Demystified)

---

***In x64 :***
In `x64`, only `__fastcall` exists. All other attributes are ignored.

The `x64` Application Binary Interface (ABI) uses a four register **fast-call** calling convention by default.

---

***Notice :***
When you call a function, what happens at the assembly level is all the passed-in parameters are pushed to the stack or placed in registers or placed in static storage, then the program jumps to a different area of code. The new area of code looks at the stack and expects the parameters to be placed there.

Different calling conventions push parameters in different ways. Some might push the first parameter first, or some might push the first param last. Or some might keep a parameter in a register and not push it at all.

By specifying a calling convention, you are telling the compiler how the parameters are to be pushed.

Comment: so, PARAMETERS can be passed to stack, why?
or why do i need push parameters to another site?
sorry, i'm very new in c++.

Comment: The `__cdecl` convention is "safer" because it is the caller that needs to deallocate the stack. What may happen in a `__stdcall` library is that the developer might have forgotten to deallocate the stack properly, or an attacker might inject some code by corrupting the DLL's stack (e.g. by API hooking) which is then not checked by the caller. See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511096/cdecl-or-stdcall-on-windows)

Comment: then, "calling conventions" in C++ are a safer way to call functions, avoiding some attackers inject code to corrupt my function.
searching in google...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf do you mean i refer to "or placed in registers or placed in static storage" in my answer?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf fixed

Comment: You might add some sentences about cleaning up the stack again, too, as there are differences as well (e. g. cdecl: caller; stdcall: callee).

Comment: @AndresCamiloSierraHormiga Calling conventions in general aren't a "safer" way to call functions.  _Every_ function has a calling convention.  It's the contract between the caller and the callee that both agree to adhere to so that the callee knows where to find its parameters and where to put its return value so the caller can find it.

Comment: @Miles Budnek you're right.
guys i found: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949862/what-are-the-different-calling-conventions-in-c-c-and-what-do-each-mean
...
at the second answer, that is an explaination about cdecl, fastcall, etc.

Comment: Worth noting, those calling conventions are relevant in 32-bit code only. The 64-bit ABI of the Windows API defines only a single calling convention, and you can get away with not specifying one in your code, because the choice is unambiguous.

Comment: decoration, which you describe, is only for *x86* platform and only for *extern "C"* funtions

Comment: @RbMm Fixed....

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic-Link Library, used in Windows operating system, so the entry point of DLL function should be crowned by "WINAPI" if it is running on Windows.